# Transfering customer SW requirements into requirements for internal teams

Tags: jira, business-analyst, business-improvement

What are the best or some already used techniques to transfer customer software requirements into internal teams requirements inside company?

To be more detailed, customer requirements need to be transformed somehow between various teams as epics/stories inside JIRA. What are the usual attitudes? Should be the role of Business Analyst involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone has to have a proper understanding of the various levels of requirements, and how they could relate to each other.   At minimum, everyone needs to be conscious of the fact that there *are* levels of requirement, and that they could originate from analysis of any of the levels. e.g. you can have business requirements, user requirements, and platform requirements.  They often flow in one particular direction, but they could come from anywhere, and impose subsequent requirements anywhere else.

There will need to be at least one person who is competent in speaking the language at all levels. Translation of a User requirement into what that could mean as a Product requirement, for example. In my world, that's often the PM, but could be a Systems Engineer, or Product Manager.

Exactly what the roles are called in your environment is an "it depends" type question.  Same for the process to be followed, that depends on the technical processes being followed, the management structure, and so many other things.

Check out "Mastering the Requirements Process" by Robertson and Robertson.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with a waterfall project management strategy, you should have business analysts that document the whole requirement set and get it signed off.

If you are working with an agile project management strategy like Scrum, you should have a product owner that creates the product backlog by conducting frequent meetings with the customer.

Both roles should know how to create a work breakdown structure, groom the requirements and prepare edible chunks of units of work for the developers.